# DataFrame.to_csv Error, is there any way to locate the character causing error in the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with shape 330000, 70, when I try to save it as csv a got the following error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\uff91' in position 110: character maps to

Is there any way to locate the character at position 110 in the DataFrame?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, that character maps to  [HALFWIDTH KATAKANA LETTER MU](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff91/index.htm), so it's from a block of Japanese text if that narrows it down.

Comment: Also, could you please clarify with what you mean with "locate the character at position110"? Do you just want to look at the character? Do you want to replace the character? What is the _actual_ problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Hampus Larsson, thank for your time. I had previously googled it and had seen what character it was, it is quite curious since the text in the DataFrame is in Spanish. The actual problem I'm trying to solve is first look at it and then decide whether to replace it or not. Sorry for my english, sometime is hard to me to explain exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google what \uff91 is, you may be able to filter on it, or replace it with something else

Another option - export it to excel and locate it that way.

Not elegant but it will probably get you the answer